# How can I set my future ride in iOS UBER API?

Tags: ios, swift, uber-api

I am developing application in swift integrating UBER  API, so far, everything is going fine, but I need to add feature to set future rides like real uber application. I need solution to reach out to the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scheduled rides is not currently a feature in the Uber API. As one possible solution, there will be a guide however in the future on scheduled rides deeplinks where you can deeplink into the Uber app for a scheduled ride with all information already filled in. I do not have an ETA for this however.